# Implementation of Class and properties in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a menu class with following properties.

**menu.ts**

```
export class Menu {
  SectionId:string;
  SectionName:string;
  ParentSectionId:number;
  Title:string;
  TitleOfAccess:string;
  Order:number;
  Submenu:Menu;
}
```

I am getting JSON data from a service and created an array of type menu. When I tried pushing those values in the array, it pushes all the values from JSON. But I have only these properties specified in the menu.ts

```
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  menuObj: Array<Menu>=[]; 
  constructor(private serviceObj:SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMenu()
  }
getMenu()
  {
    this.serviceObj.getMenu().subscribe(
    data=>{
      data.forEach(element => {
        this.menuObj.push(element);
      });
      console.log(data);
      console.log(this.menuObj);
    }

    )
  }
```

I have a console logged both the lists and both are same. It also pushes unwanted values also. Is it push only particular values from JSON to the array.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not support type checking and object mapping, although typescript does it. Since your application will get compiled to javascript only. So Either, you would have to write a mapper class by yourself, or use some available npm modules.

1. [json2typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2typescript)

You can implement the same libray on your own, follow this [link](http://cloudmark.github.io/Json-Mapping/) for same.